# Activate a tag when another tag clicked (:active)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to have a popup after I click the footer buttons (with transition fade effect ..but I'll work that out)

popup example I like: codepen.io/anon/pen/AIFyv

I cant seem to work out how to do it, I have read examples on here (S.O) and other placed, they make sense but when I apply it to my code (html and css) its not working.

my example:
codepen.io/anon/pen/bVmjxN

maybe my 'code' is bad ? have I written it wrong could you review it also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was not bad you just didn't tie the necessary JS for the event trigger, or make the necessary CSS classes to help the transition.

You can do all the above to make the transition very easy but cool! Here is the code I changed and the demo is on the bottom.

HTML:

```
<div id="heading1">
   <h1 id="header" class="text hide">
    CSS is cool!
    </h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text{
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

.hide{
   opacity: 0;
}
```

I used `transition: all` just as a demo, you can customize it how you want. To create a fade effect use `transition: opacity`.

JS:

```
$('.footer-links').on("click", function(){
  $('.text').toggleClass('bubble hide'); 
});
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/pjQjLg)

Comment: Thanks mate, this gives me a better start then I had :) ... I thought you could do this with just CSS, I have no problem using jQuery\Javascript just wanted to see how far I could go... Thanks again.